# Is it possible to get icons from the server at run time?

Tags: android, icons, xml-drawable

I don't want to have some icons inside the application. Can I download icons from the server? And how can this be done? Maybe I need a cache for it.

Icons converted from svg to xml.

Comment: _Can I download icons from the server?.._ Yes, sure... _how can this be done?..._ by implementing the code for the download process.... but as long as you dont show us any effort there will be no answer

Comment: yes you can do this , call the API(web service) on splash screen and by using Picasso library can cached it or download it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,sure.. you can hit API and parse parameter named iconurl and put parameter in picasso.

Like this.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(your_iconurl).fit().into(holder.your_imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Refer below sample code to load image into view:

```
String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
ImageView ivBasicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri).into(ivBasicImage);
```

Reference:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library